# Change text color of Title

Tags: objective-c, colors, title

I am doing this.

`self.navigationItem.title = @"Hello world!";`

I want to change color of this Hello world to green.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Either set the `titleTextAttributes` of the `navigationBar` of your UINavigationController, or else use a `titleView` instead of a `title` (e.g. a UILabel where you are totally in charge).

Answer (score 0):

Please check following URL:

> http://www.helpques.info/1022044/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color

URL will helpful for you.